# How to replicate/duplicate/sync/backup a local elasticsearch instance to a remote elasticsearch instance

Tags: elasticsearch, synchronization, backup

I have an elasticsearch cluster which contains only one node and is present in a local network to store data in an index (say "helloworld") pushed from sensors connected to different machines in the same local network. Now this setup is deployed in a remote place and lets say I do not have access to any machine on the local network from outside as there is no public IP to this local network (also I do not want to setup a VPN). I want to replicate/backup/sync (Realtime/Near-realtime is not a concern) the index "helloworld" to an elasticsearch instance running on a Virtual Private Server (VPS). How can this be achieved so that I get access to the data over the elasticsearch instance on the VPS ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the snapshot/restore api . 
1) create snapshot of your index
2) copy the snapshot by your self to your vps
3) restore it from other cluster.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#modules-snapshots

Comment: Thanks @Grigory, thats the solution for now.
Is there a directway where i can specify replica in the elasticsearch settings so that the node on the VPS is a replica of my local node?